# Using DATADIFF in a query (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use a DataDiff in a query so that I can also "print" the difference between the two dates, in seconds.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT vr.CodeR, vi.DateU, vl.originU, vl.destinyU, (DATEDIFF(second,vi.plannedDate,vi.SetDate) AS DiffDate)
FROM RegularU vr, Connection vl, InstantU vi
WHERE vl.codeU=vr.codeU AND vr.CodeR=vi.CodeR
```

But when I try to run it I have the error "Missing select word".
Is there a way so that I can do this in a query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `datediff` in Oracle. Where in the manual did you find that?

Answer (score 0):

You should better calculate a difference in seconds between two dates:

```
SELECT vr.CodeR, vi.DateU, vl.originU, vl.destinyU, (vi.plannedDate - vi.SetDate)*24*60*60  AS DiffDate
FROM RegularU vr, Connection vl, InstantU vi
WHERE vl.codeU=vr.codeU AND vr.CodeR=vi.CodeR
```